# Is there a Code Review Tool that Integrates with Team Foundation Server

Tags: subversion, code-review, visual-studio, tfs

We are using Team Foundation Server (TFS), and we need to start doing code reviews. I don't see anything Microsoft makes that supports code reviewing, but if I've missed something that would be the best option.

I am looking for a 3rd party tool which will integrate with TFS.

I expect that given a branch path and the trunk path it could query TFS and create a diff (by command line or otherwise.)

I would like if it actually integrated into the IDE that you could use Intellisense on the reviewee's changes and even jump into actual code using Visual Studios navigation features.

With cost not being an object is there anything available to me?

Comment: Note that visual studio online does this and has a really nice feel to it - it also lets you require N people to review a pull request before accepting it and to choose which people those are..

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I've been using Visual Studio Online, but I don't know how to give it a branch and have it generate the diff. Is that actually a thing?

Comment: Yes, if you work with its pull requests model it will actually generate pretty nice diffs for you with a place for comments etc. GitHub and other services do this just fine too. I only assume VSO also does it for TFS while other environments do it only for git. I lack TFS experience, I mostly recall reading that it works with TFS too (we use VSO with git).

Answer (score 1):

[Devart ReviewAssistant](https://www.devart.com/review-assistant/) is a convenient tool for iterative reviews in TFS. It integrates with Visual Studio and supports TFVC as well as other source control systems.